# Simplifying Reverse Triangle Code (While Loop)

Tags: python

I have successfully created a code to print a horizontally flipped triangle using a while loop. Now although it works, I was wondering if i could simplify this i.e. without using a "store" variable. But i want to keep it using a while loop

Current code is:

```
myLen = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
while myLen < 1 or myLen> 40:
      print("The number of rows must be greater than 1 and less than 40")
      myLen = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))

myNewLen=1
store=myLen
while myNewLen <=store:
      print((" "*(myLen-1))+"*" * myNewLen)
      myNewLen=myNewLen+1
      myLen=myLen-1
```

Which will print out a result of:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

I was wondering how i could simplify this code for efficiency.

Comment: `myLen` is undefined

Comment: Also for bug free optimization questions maybe consider posting here: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry i didnt include the top part of my code, let me edit

Comment: Do you have to use a while loop? @Xrin

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you still need to keep track of which row you're on and just do a little more math to see how many *'s and " "'s there should be. Hope this helps.

```
myLen = 5
i = 1
while myLen >= i:
    print( ("*" * i).rjust(myLen) )
    i += 1
```

Comment: Ah i see, this makes a lot of sense, simple and clear to the point. Thanks!

Comment: Personal preference perhaps, but I think it'd be even neater to use [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust) - the print line would then become `print(("*" * i).rjust(myLen))`